# CherryPy директория в директории

Tags: python, веб-сервер, cherrypy

Возник вопрос по поводу cherrypy. Вот пример кода:

```
class Root(object):
            @cherrypy.expose
            def login(self):
                return "Test OK"
```

В данном случае появляется путь `example.com/login` , но мне нужно сделать `example.com/user/login` . Даже не представляю как это сделать, прочитал много всего, но нужного не нашёл. Прошу помощи.

Comment: В доках 2я ссылка https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html#restful-style-dispatching

Comment: Моя оплошность что не заметил, спасибо огромное!